# Ranking with Nulls based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to rank customer order dates, partitioning by customer_id. I executed the below query:

```
SELECT 
sales.customer_id,
order_date,
product_name,
price,
CASE WHEN order_date>=join_date THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as member,
CASE WHEN order_date>=join_date THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sales.customer_id ORDER BY order_date, CASE WHEN order_date>=join_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END as ranking
FROM members
JOIN
sales
on members.customer_id=sales.customer_id
JOIN
menu
on sales.product_id=menu.product_id
```

I get a ranking like this

| member | ranking |
| --- | --- |
| N | NULL |
| N | NULL |
| Y | 3 |

I only want rank orders when a customer was a member like this

| member | ranking |
| --- | --- |
| N | NULL |
| N | NULL |
| Y | 1 |

How would I go about this problem in SQL Server?

Comment: You either need to partition by `CASE WHEN order_date>=join_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` rather than order by it, or change the ordering to order by this descening (so that members appear appear first)

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  The `CASE` expression in `DENSE_RANK()` should be part of the `PARTITION BY`, not `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT s.customer_id, order_date, product_name, price,
       (CASE WHEN order_date >= join_date
             THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
        END) as member,
       (CASE WHEN order_date >= join_date
            THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY s.customer_id, (CASE WHEN order_date >= join_date THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
                                    ORDER BY order_date)
        END) as ranking
FROM members m JOIN
     sales s
     ON m.customer_id = s.customer_id JOIN
     menu
     ON s.product_id = menu.product_id ;
```

Also note that I introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.  You should qualify all column names as well.